# track what function/code a thread is executing when debugging with gdb

Tags: multithreading, debugging, gdb

Is it possible for me to track what function/code a thread is executing when debugging with gdb.I do the following

```
$gdb

$gdb attach pid

$info threads 

  27   Thread 0x7f0d3a0fe700 (LWP 3418) "BgHangManager" 0x00007f0d4fd9b0af in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  26   Thread 0x7f0d389ff700 (LWP 3419) "gdbus" 0x00007f0d4f098b3d in poll () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  25   Thread 0x7f0d381fe700 (LWP 3420) "gmain" 0x00007f0d4f098b3d in poll () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  24   Thread 0x7f0d36fff700 (LWP 3422) "Timer" 0x00007f0d4fd9b458 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  23   Thread 0x7f0d3ee52700 (LWP 3423) "Cache2 I/O" 0x00007f0d4fd9b0af in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
```

$bt

```
Only gives me the stack-trace of the currently executing code while I would like to 
for know what code is exuting in another thread for instance thread 26.
```

Comment: Does `thread apply 26 bt` do what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked around it by switching to the "wanted" thread and printing the stack-trace